# Pull request is somehow showing duplicate files

Tags: git

I am having a very peculiar issue.

I was working on a project, and wanted to rename a bunch of files and folders.

i.e. src/screens/home -> src/Screens/Home

I then committed and pushed my files into a branch, and noticed that it was still committing to lower text:

`src/screens/home`

I ran the following command

`git config core.ignorecase false`

which resolved the issue.

Now my pull request is showing dup files, but on my machine it is showing correctly.

On the pull request I see both
`src/screens/home` and
`src/Screens/Home`

when I make a local change on my machine, and see the git status, it shows:

```
    modified:   src/Screens/Intro/AccountCreate/AccountCreate.js
    modified:   src/screens/Intro/AccountCreate/AccountCreate.js
```

any ideas what the hell its doing

Comment: *Setting* `core.ignorecase` amounts to lying to Git. The value here, false or true, is supposed to tell Git how your local machine / file-system actually works. When you change it, you're telling Git that your file-system works the other way, but you probably haven't actually changed how your file-system really works. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that GitHub is using a case sensitive file system, but your local file system of your OS (macOS or Windows?) is case insensitive (but case preserving).

Comment: Yeah this is a terrible quirk of using git on Windows

Answer (score 1):

Fixing this is easy, but annoying.

1. On your machine, move the files from `src/Screens` to `src/_screens`.
2. Commit these changes.
3. Move those files from `src/_screens` to `src/screens`
4. Commit these changes again.

Yeah, your commit history is a little cluttered, but at least the file paths match now.